# Problem on a bipartite graph of materials and storage facilities

Tags: graph-theory, bipartite-graphs

There is a mining site that mines different kinds of materials. Then there are storage facilities that can store those materials in warehouses (all warehouses at a given storage facility are identical but two warehouses at two different facilities might be different). If we choose to store material $m$ in storage facility $s$, the warehouses at that storage facility will be $p_{s,m} \in (0,1]$ percent filled. Certain materials can't even be stored in certain storage facilities (the warehouses there are incompatible).

We want to cover all the materials and also all the storage facilities (none of them should receive no material so people there aren't unemployed and all materials should be stored somewhere). How can we do this with a minimum number of warehouses built?

Given the list of materials, list of storage facilities, edges between materials and storage facilities (presence of edge means the storage facility can store that material) and $p_{s,m}$ (proportion of storage facility $s$ that will be filled with material $m$) associated with each of those edges, come up with an algorithm that gives us the minimum number of warehouses to be built and runs in time polynomial in the number of materials, storage facilities and edge connections.

---

**An example**

As an example, consider that there are three storage facilities, $s_1, s_2, s_3$ and two materials mined, $m_1, m_2$. The relationship between them is shown in the figure below. $m_1$ can be stored in $s_1$ but will take up 50% of the capacity of a warehouse built there. In this case, we'll need to build three warehouses; one at each of the storage facilities to cover all storage facilities and all materials (shown by the pink lines). We build one warehouse at $s_1$ and store $m_1$ there which takes up 50% of the capacity of that warehouse. Now, we have to cover $s_2$, so we build a warehouse there as well. Since $m_1$ is the only material that can be stored there, we do that and this takes up 90% of the capacity of this second warehouse. Finally, we build a warehouse at $s_3$ and store $m_2$ there which takes up 60% of the storage capacity. At this point, we've covered all three warehouses and both materials, so we're done. And we can be sure the three warehouses we built is minimal since we had to cover all three storage facilities (and all 2 materials). So 3 was always the smallest we could have gotten away with.

If at any site, adding a new material to a warehouse would have exceeded 100% of the storage capacity, we would have had to build another warehouse (which didn't happen in this case). For example, storing $m_1$ at $s_3$ would have been a bad move since $m_2$ can only be stored at $s_3$ and one warehouse there there isn't big enough to store both $m_1$ and $m_2$ (.6+.5>1). So, we'd have to build 2 warehouses at $s_3$ and then one each at $s_1$ and $s_2$ to cover them as well for a total of 4 warehouses which we know is sub-optimal.

[image]

---

**My attempt**

We can think of the storage facilities and materials as a bi-partite graph. Each edge of the graph has a weight given by $p_{s,m}$. We can do a min-weight edge cover and get the edges that cover all materials and storage facilities in a way that the sum of proportions is minimized. Then, we can loop through each storage facility, get the materials to be stored there (the edges connecting it to each of the materials after doing the edge cover) and build the minimum number of warehouses to house all materials (for example, if $\sum_{m\in S_m} p_{s,m}=1.3$ where $S_m$ is the set of materials connected to storage facility $s$ in the min weighted edge cover we ran; then we'll need to build two warehouses there since one isn't enough).

However, this is just a heuristic and not an optimal algorithm.

Comment: What is the relationship between warehouses and storage facilities and sites?

Comment: Warehouses are built at the storage facilities. All warehouses at a given storage facility are identical. The mining site is the place where materials are mined. Editing the question to remove confusion.

Comment: So rather than "minimum warehouses built", we could just think of this problem in terms of what is the minimum number of storage facilities such that all materials are stored?

Comment: No, the number of storage facilities is an input and fixed. For some graphs, we might get away with building one warehouse each at all the storage facilities (that will definitely cover all storage facilities and might also cover all materials). But for other graphs, we might need to build more than one warehouse at some of the storage facilities. So, the number of warehouses to be built is the objective function. Note: we can assume the graph is such that it makes the problem feasible.

Comment: I'm sorry, the question is still unclear to me. What does it mean to cover all materials, and what does it mean for a warehouse to be a "percent filled"? If I allocate material $m_1$ to storage facility $s_1$ and $p_{s_1, m_1} = 0.5$, does that mean I have satisfied the need to store $m_1$, and I can still store other materials in the warehouse at $s_1$? Or does that mean I've only stored half the amount of $m_1$ I need to, so I need to find some other warehouse to store more $m_1$ in? Could you rephrase the question, perhaps in terms of what a feasible solution is?

Comment: I added an example, hope it clarifies the problem. Yes, if you allocate $m_1$ to $s_1$, you have satisfied the need to cover *both* $m_1$ and $s_1$. And you've built one warehouse. But imagine there is another material, $m_2$ that can only be stored at $s_1$ and requires 51% warehouse capacity. Now you'll have to build a second warehouse to hold $m_2$. If it used 50% of capacity however, the existing warehouse could have been used to hold it as well and you wouldn't have had to pay the penalty of building one more warehouse.

Comment: I don't know a polynomial algorithm for this, however, it can be written as an integer linear programming problem, with one variable for each edge representing whether the edge is in the final edge cover and one variable for each storage facility representing the number of warehouses built there.